# Show that a "smooth" curve intersects boundary of small enough ball at two points

Tags: analysis, differential-topology, curves, plane-curves

Given a "smooth" (non selfintersecting) curve $f:[0,1] ->$ $\mathbb{R}^2$. $t\in (0,1)$ I want to show that for small enough $r$, there are exactly two points $t_1,t_2$ for which $$\| f(t_i)- f(t) \|_2 =r $$ and further $t_1<t<t_2$.

Not sure how much smoothness is needed.

Comment: It seems to me that you just need your curve to be regular ($f'$ exists and $f'(t)\neq 0$). For $\tilde t\sim t$, your curve can be approximated by the tangent up to linear order. The tangent intersects the boundary of the disk at two points, and so should $f(t)$. I believe this can be made precise.